# Remove network adapter windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, devcon

Good day to you all.
I am a beginner in the batch-file.
Why doesn't my code want to work properly? In what direction to dig?

```
    for /F %%a in ('devcon driverfiles ^=net ^| find "PCI\"') do ( 
        devcon remove %%a
    )
```

[Devcon give an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSS9M.png)

```
    for /F %%a in ('devcon driverfiles ^=net ^| find "PCI\"') do ( 
       devcon remove PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0036&SUBSYS_020C1028&REV_01\4&7A7034C&0&00E2 
    )
```

If you directly set to `for`, it works correctly, why it happens?
[Devcon works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxiE8.png)

Comment: 1st avoid the default delims `for /f "delims="` 2nd double quote `"%%a"` to avoid the `&`-signs being interpreted as command concatenation. 3rd you do run the batch elevated?

Comment: I'm not sure why you've decided to use a [tag:for-loop] for this task when it looks as if it could be done directly, e.g. `devcon remove =net @pci\*`

Comment: @LotPings tried all your tips, in different variations. Unsuccessfully..

Comment: @Compo Working option. `devcon remove PCI\*` It removes 10 devices instead of two. Thanks. I will think in this direction

Comment: @Compo Thanks. This works great for me. `devcon remove =net PCI\*`